# Export one table / MySQL

Tags: mysql, export

I try to export one table of my database as an sql file. I looked into several topics and found the code snippet at the end. Every time I try to export the table I get an error message that I have syntax error. Some suggestions how to do it correctly?

` mysqldump -u root -p my_database table1 > export.sql;

Comment: mysqldump is a command line program. it's NOT a command you enter at the `mysql>` prompt...

Comment: ok, is there are a mysql command ?